# terraform | aws_launch_template restricts version limits

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, autoscaling

In AWS, while creating launch_template, there is an option to delete versions. but in terraform, I don't see any attributes that do that.

With each deployment, I see it creates a new aws launch template and doesn't remove the old one.

Is there any option to delete / restrict the number of version to have at one of time?